# Accessing target of a windows shorcut

Tags: r, windows, shortcut-file

In linux machines, it is possible to access where a symbolic link is pointing to by using `Sys.readlink` function in R or `readlink` from the command line. Reading its documentation, we see that this is not intended for Windows shortcuts.

In Windows I have not been able to find a one liner to give me where the file points to. The closest I got was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188485/windows-symbolic-link-target) SO question that demonstrates the use of `dir`. While the output was not perfect I figured with some regex magic I could isolate the file path.

However when I tried `system2('dir')`, I received the error `"dir" not found`.

Is there (a better) way for me to access the file path of a Windows shortcut from R and why can't I use `dir` through a system call in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future finding this thread, the answer is [`fs::link_path()`](http://fs.r-lib.org/reference/link_path.html) [as pointed out by Edward Visel](https://twitter.com/alistaire/status/961306620478263298)