# PHP Laravel 8 photos are not showing

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, photo

The photos in **Laravel 8** are not showing in html "the alternative text is showing instead".
In windows file explorer, I found each photo as a **folder** with the name of the photo for example "**myphoto.jpg**" and inside this folder there is a "**.tmp**" file.
the destination folder is "**uploads/posts**" and when I inspect the photo in the browser, the link is shown correctly.
here's a link example of one photo: "http://localhost/laravel/blog/uploads/posts/1657160399photo.jpg".

and when I access it directly from the browser, I get "404 Not Found".
I tried to add the following code inside filesystems.php inside "links" but it didn't work as well, the code line is:

```
public_path('uploads/posts') => storage_path('app/uploads/posts')
```

and in the terminal I also executed the following command but to no avail:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I'll put below some related code from **filesystems.php**:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and

```
 'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),

        //added by me
        public_path('uploads/posts') => storage_path('app/uploads/posts')
    
    ],
```

and one last note .. I used .htaccess in my root folder just to get rid of "public" from the link.. for example if I want to go to posts page I write :

http://localhost/laravel/blog/posts

insted of:
http://localhost/laravel/blog/public/posts

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow php_man. did you verify that the symlinks are made? what os are you using? have you tried to narrow down the problem by **disabling** that rewrite rule that removes `public` from your url?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @BagusTesa .. I tried to remove the .htaccess, same problem .. the symlinks that I mentioned above "inside filesystems.php" -> I'm not sure if this is a correct way' .. The OS is windows ..

Comment: `filesystem.php` is not the `symlink`. its a config telling laravel which stuff are where. [you can check whether you have `symlink` using `dir` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188485/windows-symbolic-link-target).

Comment: Thanks again @BagusTesa , The thing is, I changed the function used to save the images from move( ) to store( ), then I found the images getting saved inside: 'Storage/uploads/posts' insted of 'uploads/posts' folder that I created.. so what do I need to do next if you could help please ..

Comment: @BagusTesa even if I open the file in the browser with the link in storage/uploads/posts , it will give me 404 Not Found .. the same exact link .. and the image is there with the original extenstion (not tmp) .. still 404 :'(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a file response in Blade as the img source

```
<img src="{{ response()->file($pathToFile) }}">
```

For more information check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-responses

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, I tried it but unfortunately the image still doesn't show and if I inspect it and open its link from the browser, it gives me 404 not found .. while the image exists in file explorer ....

Comment: well, should we add the photos in the public folder? cuz it worked when I tried in the public folder ! .. is that mandatory ?.. also what should we do to prevent direct access to these photos? becuase they should be private as they are used as profile pictures

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes, the picture has to be publicly available. Either under /public but better under /storage/app/public. Don't forget to create the symlink. These 'disks' are already predefined in the /config/filesystem.php settings file.